# 2 completely different queries in 1 statement mysql

Tags: php, mysql

Not sure if this can be done but I would like to ask 2 completely different quires calling different tables in one statement. The end result would either be the amount of records found which would either be 0 or greater than.

I understand about using [Multiple Statements](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.multiple-statement.php#mysqli.quickstart.multiple-statement) in php but is my understanding that this will execute each one individually in order which is not what I need to do. I need to know if either statement produces any records.

**Query #1**

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM table1 WHERE company_id = '$company_id ' AND email = '$email'";
```

OR

**Query #2**

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM table2 WHERE company_id = '$company_id ' AND column = 1";
```

I need to combine these with an `OR` because if either one produces records then I need to continue.

Ultimately

```
$sql = "(SELECT * FROM table1 WHERE company_id = '$company_id ' AND email = '$email') OR (SELECT * FROM table2 WHERE company_id = '$company_id ' AND column = 1)";
$result = $conn->query($sql);
if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
    // do something
}
```

Comment: If they have the same fields you can use `UNION`, but there is no such thing as "ORing" result sets together.

Comment: Yeah not matching fields, both different

Comment: The pattern in the code example is a pattern that appears to be vulnerable to SQL Injection... we don't see any guarantee that the values of the variables are *safe* for inclusion in the SQL text.

Comment: Are you using the actual data, or do you just need to know if there is data?

Comment: Have you tried SQL Transaction, not sure but just asking

Comment: I just need to know if there is any data so I don't have to use `*` there is actually one matching field in both table and its the primary `ID` but they do not join together on these fields nor do they match.

Comment: If `id` is the same datatype in both tables, and ideally a non-NULL column in both tables, then we could use query... `SELECT t1.id FROM table1 t1 WHERE ... UNION ALL SELECT t2.id FROM table2 t2 WHERE ...`.  Otherwise, we can just use a literal in the SELECT list `SELECT 1 FROM table1 WHERE ... UNION ALL SELECT 2 FROM table2 WHERE ... `

Comment: I also recommend ditching the `SELECT *` pattern where we don't need to return all of the columns.  Better to list just the expressions that we actually need, that gives more opportunity for database tuning/performance improvements, with more efficient access plans using suitable covering indexes, etc. It also aids the future reader, when `*` includes a few columns we care about amongst a multitude of columns that we don't... we leave the reader with the job of figuring out which is which. Saving a few dozen keystrokes by typing `SELECT *` just isn't worth it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you just need to know whether there is data, and not what that data is, this should suffice:

```
SELECT CASE WHEN (EXISTS (SELECT * FROM table1 WHERE company_id = '$company_id ' AND email = '$email') 
    OR EXISTS (SELECT * FROM table2 WHERE company_id = '$company_id ' AND column = 1)
) THEN 1 ELSE 0 END AS hasData;
```

It also happens to be the most literal expression of what you are looking for.

Note that instead of checking num_rows, you'll need to check the field value on the single column of the single result row returned.

Comment: so `if ($row['hasData'] != '') {` ?

Comment: The `exists or exists` should result in a bool, but since those can be kind of vague in MySQL, I've updated the answer so it will return 1 (has data) or 0 (no data). _I'm not familiar enough with php syntax to say the exact method calls offhand to get to the row, but that looks right (other than the 1/0 change i just made) as far as I can tell._

Answer (score 0):

Assumin that the two table contain the same  column  You could use UNION (for distinct rows)

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM table1 WHERE company_id = '$company_id ' AND email = '$email'
      UNION 
      SELECT * FROM table2 WHERE company_id = '$company_id ' AND column = 1";
```

OR UNION ALL if you need  all rows dupicated  included

otherwise you should explicitally  name the column you need

```
$sql = "SELECT col1, col2, col3 ... FROM table1 WHERE company_id = '$company_id ' AND email = '$email'
      UNION 
      SELECT col1, col2, col3 ... FROM table2 WHERE company_id = '$company_id ' AND column = 1";
```

and last be careful using php var is sql  .. you should check for you db driver for param binding for avoid sql injection

Comment: This pattern (using * in the SELECT list) would require that the number of columns in `table1` matches the number of columns in `table2`, and that the datatypes of the corresponding columns in the two sets "match" (or can be coerced into matching.) The code in this answer follows a pattern that appears to be vulnerable to SQL Injection.

Comment: @spencer7593  correct  .. answer  updated  with you suggestion  too

Answer (score 0):

The query below will l return the number of rows matched and the query that matched the rows. If only one query returns rows, the output will be one row, if both queries match, it will return two rows.

```
SELECT 
    '1' as `querythatmatched`,
    COUNT(*) as `nummatched`
FROM TABLE1
WHERE `company_id` = '$company_id' AND `email` = '$email'
UNION
SELECT 
    '2' as `querythatmatched`,
    COUNT(*) as `nummatched`
FROM TABLE2
WHERE `company_id` = '$company_id' AND `column` = 1;
```

BTW, This doesn't care what columns exist in the two tables (except in the where clauses), so it can be used for any table/column types.

Comment: This query (if execution is successful) is guaranteed to return two rows, OP will need to fetch the rows and inspect the value of `nummatched` to determine if any matching row exists. Nothing wrong with doing that... but the `->num_rows` pattern in OP code will have to be changed.

Answer (score 0):

Not to add to the confusion, several viable alternatives are proposed.

For succinctness, I would go with a very simple SQL query, something like this:

```
 SELECT 1 FROM table1 t1 WHERE t1.company_id ...
 UNION ALL
 SELECT 2 FROM table2 t2 WHERE t2.company_id ...
```

I'd also address what appears to be a *gaping* SQL Injection vulnerability... we don't see any evidence that the variables e.g. $company_id are guaranteed to be safe for inclusion in SQL text.

If we're not going to use prepared statements with bind placeholders, then we need to properly escape the values to be included in the SQL

either inline in generating the SQL text

```
 $sql = "SELECT 1 FROM table1 t1 WHERE t1.company_id = "
      . "'" . $conn->real_escape_string($company_id) . "'"
      . " AND t1.email = "
      . "'" . $conn->real_escape_string($email) . "'"
      . " UNION ALL"
      . " SELECT 2 FROM table2 t2 WHERE t2.company_id = "
      . "'" . $conn->real_escape_string($company_id) . "'"
      . " AND t2.column = 1" ;
```

*-or-*

as separate assignments immediately preceding the construction of the SQL

```
 $es_company_id = $conn->real_escape_string($company_id);
 $es_email      = $conn->real_escape_string($email);
 $sql = "SELECT 1 FROM table1 t1 WHERE t1.company_id = '$es_company_id'"
      . " AND t1.email = '$es_email'"
      . " UNION ALL"
      . " SELECT 2 FROM table2 t2 WHERE t2.company_id = '$es_company_id'"
      . " AND t2.column = 1" ;
```

Answer (score 0):

@Uueerdo has an effective answer (notwithstanding the SQL injection thing but that's not what the OP asked). If I may offer a slight change to improve the speed of the query, I'd offer this:

```
SELECT CASE WHEN (EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM table1 WHERE company_id ='$company_id ' AND email = '$email') 
    OR EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM table2 WHERE company_id = '$company_id ' AND column = 1)
) THEN 1 ELSE 0 END AS hasData;
```

I benchmarked this in SQLYog and found the Total execution time to be 0.00055 when `SELECT 1` is used in the subselects instead of `SELECT *`. With the `SELECT *`, the Total execution time was 0.01237. I hope someone finds it useful to learn that `SELECT *` should probably not be used in Production environments.